# Hide column in ui grid if no data present

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to hide columns in ui-grid if there is no data present in that column. Like here the column "**Issued By**" and "**Issued On**" should be hidden as there is no data present.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="appHome">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlRequestDetail">
        <div class="gridStyle" ui-grid="gridInvUsage">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('appHome', ['ui.grid']);

myApp.controller("ctrlRequestDetail", ['$scope', 'MetadataOrgFactory', function ($scope, MetadataOrgFactory) {
    MetadataOrgFactory.getIdApiCall('geteventinvlist', $scope.reqDetailData.EventId, function (dataSuccess) {
        //Web API call to Fetch Data
        $scope.invUsageData = dataSuccess;        
    }, function (dataError) {
    });

    $scope.gridInvUsage = {
        data: 'invUsageData',
        columnDefs: [           
            { field: 'InvBookStartTime', displayName: 'Book Start Time', cellFilter: 'date:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"' },
            { field: 'InvBookEndTime', displayName: 'Book End Time', cellFilter: 'date:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"' },
            { field: 'SourceInvNumber', displayName: 'Source Inventory' },
            { field: 'BookingRemarks', displayName: 'Booking Remarks' },
            { field: 'BookingStatus', displayName: 'Booking Status' },
            { field: 'AcceptRejectBy', displayName: 'Accept/Reject By' },
            { field: 'IssuedBy', displayName: 'Issued By' },
            { field: 'IssuedOnTime', displayName: 'Issued On' },           
        ]

    }
}])
```

How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: check the documentation of ui-grid on the toggle button http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/113_adding_and_removing_columns

Comment: can you provide some sample working plunk ?

Comment: Hi @Jesus - I get your example but my requirement is slightly different. I want to hide columns if there is no data present at all. Please help me on that and let me know if I miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily toggle the particular column `visible` property to show and hide the based on arrived data from API.

**Code**

```
$scope.columns = [           
    { field: 'InvBookStartTime', displayName: 'Book Start Time', cellFilter: 'date:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"' },
    { field: 'InvBookEndTime', displayName: 'Book End Time', cellFilter: 'date:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"' },
    { field: 'SourceInvNumber', displayName: 'Source Inventory' },
    { field: 'BookingRemarks', displayName: 'Booking Remarks' },
    { field: 'BookingStatus', displayName: 'Booking Status' },
    { field: 'AcceptRejectBy', displayName: 'Accept/Reject By' },
    { field: 'IssuedBy', displayName: 'Issued By' },
    { field: 'IssuedOnTime', displayName: 'Issued On' },           
];

$scope.gridOptions = {
   data: 'invUsageData',
   columnDefs: $scope.columns,
   onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
   }
};

//Once data arrives, inside ajax success
//Web API call to Fetch Data
$scope.invUsageData = dataSuccess;  
$scope.columns.forEach(function(col){
   col.visible = $scope.invUsageData.filter(function(item){
       return angular.isDefined(item[col. field]);
   }).length;
});
```

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zbgwRdSfUNaNW346ghdj?p=preview)

---

Retrieve column definition via ajax and after updating `columnDefs` property refresh the grid to see the changes

```
function getColumns() {
  $http.get('columns.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.columns = response.data;
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = $scope.columns;
    $scope.columns.forEach(function(col) {
      col.visible = $scope.invUsageData.filter(function(item) {
        return angular.isDefined(item[col.field]);
      }).length;
    });
    //updated grid after colDef changed.
    $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
  });
}

$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'invUsageData',
  columnDefs: $scope.columns,
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  }
};
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ROCYonHsXWtG3nIRGFo0?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the input. But how does the variable "col" sets in the line "$scope.columns.forEach(function(col)". I tried your code but the execution point never reaches inside foreach function. If you explain this then it will be really helpful.

Comment: Did you check plunker?

Comment: Yes I checked it. It is showing the preview with two columns but neither the buttons are working nor the columns are getting hidden if there is no data. I might be doing some mistake. it will be really helpful if you point out my mistake and how to take the execution control inside the forEach function

Comment: In my demo `InvBookStartTime` & `InvBookEndTime` column has data. Since other column has no data, you will only see these two columns

Comment: I completely agree with you. But in my case after the data fetched successfully it tries to execute foreach loop but it never happened because it didnt find "col" paraneter that has been passed in the function. Can you please tell me how this function be called or will this function is getting called automatically?

Comment: Are you retrieving column from Server call?

Comment: Yes column data is retrieved from WebAPI call

Comment: Then you should be doing that column formatting when ajax succeed.

Comment: @user1843970 I updated the answer for you, Thanks :)

Comment: Thank You Pankaj for your updated answer. I have tried the things but stuck at one place. Like you mentioned that ""col.visible"" as ""return angular.isDefined(item[col.field]);"". This is fine if any column is not defined in JSON but what code to write if column is defined in JSON but has empty value. I tried and see that in  such cases column appears in ui-grid even if there is empty value inside. Can you please help here?